# Checking pipe state

Tags: c, printf, pipe

I create a named posix pipe, say pipe_out, using

```
mkfifo $path_tmp/pipe_out
```

open it in C

```
out_pipe = fopen(TMP_PATH "/pipe_out", "w");
```

and write to it using the fprintf command

```
fprintf(out_pipe,"%s",string);
```

I guess I could use the return value of fprintf to check how much was written and compare it to the actuall length of the string, to know if the complete string was written to the pipe. Then, if it is (over-)full, I pause somehow and try to write again in an endless loop starting with what was not yet written...

What would this look like in detailed and is there maybe a more advanced way which stalls (pauses) fprintf  automatically when the pipe is full.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pro-actively detect when the pipe is full, using `fprintf()` is not a good idea because it will internally buffer your data.

Even if the pipe fd is not writable anymore, fprintf() will continue to return unless the internal buffer is also full. In that case, it will not return a shortened value but block until it can write/buffer the whole string.

If you want to detect pipe state, you should not use buffered function but:

- open() to open fifo/pipe
- select() to test is file descriptor is writable
- write() to write string (return value must be handled)